# How can I know how much dedicated video memory in AMD GPU (NOT Intel) and increase it? (Dual GPU Laptop)

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, amd-radeon, dual-gpu

Yo, I tried checking my AMD GPU Graphics card dedicated memory in my dual GPU laptop but I when I right-click on Desktop -> Screen Resolution then Advanced settings, I see only Intel and not AMD. So, How can I check the dedicated memory value of the AMD? and How can I increase it for AMD? Because I'm not sure if I reduced my System RAM, will it be for AMD or Intel and\or if there's another way especially for the Dual-Laptops.?

- Inspiron 5547 **A11** Bios { **Dell Laptop** }
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.60 GHz
- Intel HD Graphics 4400 **&&** AMD Radeon R7 M260.
- 8.00 GBytes DDR3 Memory (7.89 GB usable)

Comment: Please edit your question to include make/model of the PC and make/model of the video hardware(s).  There might be a BIOS setting to control the amount of RAM dedicated to the integrated graphics.  I've seen that setting on two Intel-based SFF PCs, so I the same might be available for you.  The discrete card has a definite amount of RAM on it, so that part can't be adjusted.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I done editing it. Even if it's not available, I want to know at least how to view the Dedicated VRAM or even the shared-system memory (**of AMD**) from Win7

Comment: To adjust the integrated graphics RAM, boot into the BIOS (repeatedly press F2 while booting to see the option) .  Look in the Configuration tab, in the IGD DVMT Memory section.  https://communities.intel.com/thread/55054 .  However, that's just for the integrated graphics.  It's my understanding that dedicated graphics cards only use their onboard RAM.  A program like GPU-Z may show you the stat that you want, but I don't think you'll be able to change it.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I already tried GPU-Z before posting this question. It only shows the memory-size which I can get from my Radeon settings easily (2048 MB). Only memory-size, no more details about the VRAM like shared-system memory, dedicated etc.. p.s I only want for my AMD.. If I decreased the maximum RAM for PC from the `msconfig` command, I noticed that my Intel GPU total memory also decreases. Does that mean it goes to the AMD total memory or it just gone unusable? (That's why I want to know the AMD VRAM details, to check if it increases or have any reaction to that)

Comment: No, and you need to understand this: The amount of memory used by the integrated card (Intel) can be changed in BIOS/UEFI. The amount of memory used by the discrete card (AMD) **is fixed**, it can't be changed or added to from the system's memory.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ok..... :

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot increase the amount of RAM available to your AMD GPU.  The GPU uses its own dedicated memory chips that are soldered to your motherboard.  So if it came with 2GB of VRAM, then you'll always have 2GB of VRAM.  The discrete GPU does not use your system RAM at all.

As for the integrated Intel GPU, there *might* be a setting in your firmware for that.  If there is, then that's the only way to change it.  If there isn't, then you're out of luck.  It's probably stuck at 512MB or whatever and you'll be unable to change it.

Be aware that in neither case can one GPU use the other GPU's memory.  The discrete (AMD) GPU has its own RAM, and the integrated Intel GPU reserves a portion of your system RAM.